# Popup & Greyout background

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am trying to create a small popup window with some info and grey-out the background.

my php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="help-file/js-funct.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="all">
<div id="frpic"><img src="one.jpg" /></div>

<div id="frdesc">
<span class="txt-frdes">
<a id="lnk-s" class="pop-lnk">more...</a>
</span>
</div>

<br />
<div id="popup" class="hide-it"></div>
<br />
<div id="gr-out" class="hide-it"></div>
</div></body></html>
```

my js-funct:

```
(document).ready(function(){
 $('#all')
///////LINKS////////
  .delegate... other functions
///////POPUP///////
 .delegate('a.pop-lnk', 'click', function(){
  var page = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#gr-out').css({ opacity: 0.7, 'width':$(document).width(),'height':$(document).height()});
  $('#popup').css({'display': 'block'});
  $('#popup').load("../help-file/loop-b.php?page="+ page);
 })

 .delegate('.hide-it', 'click', function(){ 
  $('.hide-it').hide();
 });

});
```

my css:

```
div#popup{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%; left: 50%;
 height: 310px; width: 310px;
 margin-top: -155px; margin-left: -155px;
 padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
 z-index: 20;
 display: none;
 text-align: justify;
}
    div#gr-out{
     position: absolute;
     top: 0; left: 0;
     background: #000;
    }
```

Jaymin **before I read** your answer I did change my JQ code to the above: Now.. the above change works **BUT** only the 1st time. When I click on document it takes me back to page and then if I click again on my link, I get the popup but without the grey-out.

Comment: you should confirm `z-index`. It may make the layer lower others and you can't find them. Please put the **css** on the question.

Comment: Is there anything about console log or error?

Comment: sorry my connection went down. no there is no error or anything. Is like I am clicking on a dead link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Take your popup divs out of other divs so they can work without affected by other CSS.
2. Delegate is use for creating events on element which are loaded after page load , during Ajax or by any other way. Also it have three arguments and as per your code you don't need it .

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaymingajjar/pgq4a5w7/) : http://jsfiddle.net/jaymingajjar/pgq4a5w7/

Here is corrected code which work for me :

**PHP**

```
<body>
    <div id="all">
        <div id="frpic"><img src="one.jpg" /></div>
        <div id="frdesc">
            <span class="txt-frdes">
                <a id="lnk-s" class="pop-lnk">more...</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup" class="hide-it"></div>
    <div id="gr-out" class="hide-it"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#popup{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    height: 310px; width: 310px;
    margin-top: -155px; margin-left: -155px;
    padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
    z-index: 20;
    display: none;
    text-align: justify;
}
div#gr-out{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background: #000;
}
```

**Javascript : Edited**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#all')
    ///////LINKS////////
    //.delegate... other functions
    ///////POPUP///////
    $('#all').delegate('a.pop-lnk', 'click', function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#gr-out').css({ opacity: 0.7, 'width':$(document).width(),'height':$(document).height()}).show();
        $('#popup').css({'display': 'block'});
        $('#popup').load("../help-file/loop-b.php?page="+ page);
    })
    $('body').delegate('.hide-it', 'click', function(){ 
        $('.hide-it').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I read your answer before I change my code a bit. can you re-help me pls? :) or anyone else?

Comment: I've just tried it but is behaving like my version. 1st time ok. 2nd time only the popup shows up. No gray-out.

Comment: I have added Jsfiddle link in answer , and it is working perfectly. Let me know if any other help needed.

Comment: oh... thank you very much. I was missing **.show();** from my code. is working perfectly now. Thank you again.